# How to install Brother Control Center 3 without DVD (for MFC-260C)?

Tags: multi-function-printer

I cannot remember where I put the DVD of my brother MFC-260C all-in-one printer.

**How to install Brother Control Center 3 for this model?**

I downloaded the "**Full Driver and Software package** (recommended)":
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=mfc260c_eu_as&os=93
It does install the driver, but not the "Control Center 3".

Then, I tried installing the "ControlCenter3 Update Tool" from the same page, but the install is impossible since the "MFL-Pro" software is missing.

Lastly, I tried installing the "MFL-Pro" from the DVD of my Brother DCP-9020CDW, but the installer doesn't detect the USB-connected printer (probably because it is a MFC-260C). The Control Center 3 still does not install. (I can access the list of files of the DVD if necessary.)

Comment: OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: You should edit your question and include information like that in the question body instead of submitting temporary commentary.